# More Info Wanted. Specialized Tarmac SL5 frame

Tags: identify-this-bike, specialized-bikes, customization

Can someone please provide me more info regarding a Specialized SL5 frame? It is a rim brake frame, possibly 2015/6 model?

Appreciate it, thanks [image]

Comment: What kind of "more info" are you after? Have you searched the internet for `specialized sl5` to see what comes up? What's missing after doing said search?

Comment: Here are a few [photos](https://99spokes.com/en-EU/bikes?category=road&family=specialized-tarmac&frameMaterial=carbon&makerId=specialized&year=2015%2C2016) of 2015/16 Tarmac models. I might be wrong but the colorway looks way to 90s MTB-ish for an original 2010s paintjob, I haven't found any pictures with Tarmac on the _inside_ of the chainstays and the seatpost looks straighter compared to the original ones. Is there any UCI badging in the seattube/BB area?

Comment: The BB cups are black on pretty much all SL5 frameset pictures I've seen, no matter the color. These matching the frame also indicates at least a repaint.

Comment: ... but: many details are matching Tarmac frames, for example the area where the seatstays meet the seat/toptube and the braze-on mount for the front derailleur. So yeah, it might be an original frame (or a good fake?) but would I buy it from Ebay without a credible history and/or invoice/certificates? No.